# Sliding Animation NSView background color in swift

Tags: swift, macos, animation, nsview

Trying to modifying the color of `NSView` with sliding animation like [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/visualize?pn=p1&nrow=2&ncol=2)

```
let hexColors = ["56A55B", "4F86EC", "F2BC42", "DA5040"]

@IBAction func changeColor(sender: NSButton) {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hexColors.count)))
    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({_ in
        //duration
        NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 5.0
        self.view.animator().layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(hex: hexColors[randomIndex]).cgColor
    }, completionHandler:{
        print("completed")
    })
}
```

I tried using `NSAnimationContext` to set duration of color change, but it does not work. However it works with the `alphaValue` of the view.

Comment: Ther aren't modifiing background colors, they changing views

Comment: @yerpy How is that changing view? The background color is still changed but without duration.

Comment: The view is trasiting from one of the side and overlaping the view behinde, probably you could use collection view and each cell would have 2 views, even though you could have a stack view, one view would have width = 0 and second one view width = stack view width. But still you would have left - right transition. It seems like carousel effect.

Comment: Oh! you are talking about the google trends page. Adding a `subview` for a small duration is an overhead. Because you don't want to stack many subviews (or have to deal with removing the previous subview). That's why I was going for the background animation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have gotten your answer yet. But this might be able get it to work:

```
let hexColors = ["56A55B", "4F86EC", "F2BC42", "DA5040"]

@IBAction func changeColor(sender: NSButton) {
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hexColors.count)))
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
    //duration
    context.duration = 5.0
    
    // This is the key property that needs to be set
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true

    self.view.animator().layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(hex: hexColors[randomIndex]).cgColor
}, completionHandler:{
    print("completed")
})
}
```

here is what the documentation says:

```
/* Determine if animations are enabled or not. Using the -animator proxy will automatically set allowsImplicitAnimation to YES. When YES, other properties can implicitly animate along with the initially changed property. For instance, calling [[view animator] setFrame:frame] will allow subviews to also animate their frame positions. This is only applicable when layer backed on Mac OS 10.8 and later. The default value is NO.
 */
@available(macOS 10.8, *)
open var allowsImplicitAnimation: Bool
```